# Correct way to hardcode an image into a parent theme file?

Tags: bloginfo

I wanted to ask if ths is the best practice for calling an image into a parent theme file by using bloginfo('template_directory')?

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.jpg" />
```

or should one use:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/img/logo.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Codex, the use of `get_bloginfo()` for certain parameters is discouraged:

> - '**stylesheet_url'** - Returns the primary [CSS](/Glossary#CSS) (usually *style.css*) file URL of the active theme. Consider using  [get_stylesheet_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri) instead.
> - '**stylesheet_directory'** - Returns the stylesheet directory URL of the active theme. (Was a local path in earlier WordPress versions.) Consider using  [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead.
> - '**template_url'** / '**template_directory'** - URL of the active theme's directory ('template_directory' was a local path before [2.6](/Version_2.6); see [get_theme_root()](/Function_Reference/get_theme_root) and [get_template()](/Function_Reference/get_template) for hackish alternatives.)  Within child themes, both get_bloginfo('template_url') and get_template() will return the *parent* theme directory. Consider using  [get_template_directory_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) instead (for the parent template directory) or  [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) (for the child template directory).

So, the answer to your question is that `bloginfo('template_directory')` is not best practice. Use one the functions listed in Codex instead--  [get_template_directory_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or  [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

I consider using `bloginfo()` as you have in the first block of code to be a kind of quasi-deprecated usage. There are functions in place to replace that usage but that being the case or not why add the overhead of `get_bloginfo()` when you can call the appropriate functions directly, and are told to do so by the Codex itself?

Comment: When I use:

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.jpg" />`

This is the output and image shows:
`<img src="http://localhost:8888/Testing/wp-content/themes/works/img/logo.jpg" />`
         
But when I use:
`<img src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.jpg" />`

Image does not show and this is the output:
`<img src="/img/logo.jpg" />`

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means.

Comment: Hi I tried to clean up my explanation above, not sure on how to create a line break so it could read easier.

Im working on MAMP.

Comment: You need to `echo` the string : `echo get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Opps so to sum up this is the best practice:
`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for `get_bloginfo`, all it is doing is calling `get_template_directory_uri` when it is passed the argument `template_directory` or `template_url`.

Note that `get_template_directory_uri` is the function for getting the *URL* whereas `get_template_directory` is the function for getting the *path*.

`bloginfo('template_directory')` and `get_template_directory_uri` are functionally equivalent, with the possible exception of filters applied to `bloginfo`.

There is nothing wrong with using either. Neither function could be called "hard coded" as they both dynamically fetch the base URL to the current theme (or parent theme when using a child theme).

Comment: You are right about the hardcode bit, took that out.

While testing on MAMP between the two it seemed more flexible to use bloginfo('template_directory');

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: To expand on this answer, if you're building a child theme you'd want to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/some/path/file.ext'